# Quotienting Isometry Group by Subgroup of Bounded Isometries

Tags: reference-request, metric-spaces, isometry

Given a metric space $(X, d),$ the set of all self-isometries $f \colon (X, d) \to (X, d)$ forms a group $$\text{Isom}(X)$$ under composition.

Let $$\text{Isom}_{0}(X) = \left\{f \in \text{Isom}(X) \mid \sup_{x \in X} d(f(x), x) < \infty\right\}$$ denote the subset of $\text{Isom}(X)$ consisting of self-isometries of $X$ which are a bounded distance away from the identity $\text{id}_{X}.$

Working through the definitions, one can show that $\text{Isom}_{0}(X)$ is a normal subgroup of $\text{Isom}(X),$ hence we can form the quotient group $$ \text{Isom}(X) /\text{Isom}_{0}(X).$$ Note that two isometries $f, g \in \text{Isom}(X)$ are mapped to the same element of $\text{Isom}(X) /\text{Isom}_{0}(X)$ by the natural projection if and only if $$\sup_{x \in X}d(f(x), g(x)) < \infty.$$

I was motivated to consider this construction because of the similar quotienting process used to construct the quasi-isometry group $\mathcal{QI}(X)$ of a metric space. My question is: **Are there any papers/books which discuss this quotient group?**

Comment: Unlikely. But what question you would like to have answered in this context? I have hard time of thinking of anything nontrivial.

Comment: @MoisheKohan One I had in mind is the following: it's easy to give examples of spaces $X$ for which this quotient group is trivial. I am also pretty sure that there are spaces $X$ for which this quotient group is infinite. But what are some spaces $X$ where this quotient group is nontrivial and finite? I apologize if this turns out to be a trivial question.

Comment: Sure, for instance, $X={\mathbb R}$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Ah, my bad! I completely forgot reflections were a thing when I was calculating for $\mathbb{R}.$ Thank you!